# Character Teleporting to side of screen when trying to move

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm very new to HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. My darthVader character keeps on teleporting to the side of the screen any time I try to do any movement. I think this might be a problem with my CSS. Also I am open to any and all suggestions for changes for this project. Whether it is efficiency, layout, or any math involved in this project. Right now I'm just learning as I go instead of watching a hand holding tutorial.

```js
//Global variables
let deathStar = document.querySelector(".deathStar")
let counter = 0;
let darthVader = document.querySelector(".darthVader");
let vaderX = window.scrollX + darthVader.getBoundingClientRect().left;
const x1 = window.scrollX + deathStar.getBoundingClientRect().left; // top left X
const y1 = window.scrollY + deathStar.getBoundingClientRect().top; // top left Y
const x2 = window.scrollY + deathStar.getBoundingClientRect().right; // bottom right X
const y2 = window.scrollY + deathStar.getBoundingClientRect().bottom; // top right Y

//Create a storm trooper
function createStormTrooper(){
    colorArray = ['blue', 'green', 'orange', 'yellow', 'white', 'red','purple', 'pink'];
    counter++;
    //create each div
    let stormTrooper = document.createElement('div');
    let body = document.createElement('div');
    let gun = document.createElement('div');
    let head = document.createElement('div');
    let legSplit = document.createElement('div');

    //append div to proper div
    deathStar.append(stormTrooper);
    stormTrooper.append(body);
    body.append(gun);
    body.append(head);
    body.append(legSplit);
    //add classes
    stormTrooper.classList.add("trooper",'stormTrooperPart' + counter, "stormTrooper");
    body.classList.add("trooper", 'stormTrooperPart' + counter, "body");
    gun.classList.add("trooper", 'stormTrooperPart' + counter, "gun");
    head.classList.add("trooper", 'stormTrooperPart' + counter, 'head');
    legSplit.classList.add("trooper", 'stormTrooperPart' + counter, "legSplit");

    let randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*8);
    body.style.backgroundColor = colorArray[randomColor];

    placeInsideDeathStar(stormTrooper);
}

//Places a trooper in a random spot inside the death star
function placeInsideDeathStar(stormTrooper){
    let midPointX = (x2 + x1) / 2;
    let midPointY = (y2 + y1) / 2;
    let radius = x2 - midPointX - 10;
    let theta = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
    let r = (Math.sqrt(Math.random()) * radius);
    let yRandom = r * Math.sin(theta);
    let xRandom = r * Math.cos(theta);
    stormTrooper.style.transform = "translate(" + (xRandom) + "px," + (yRandom) + "px)";
}

//Create Troopers
for(let i = 0; i < 10;i++ ){
    createStormTrooper();
}


//Storm Trooper Removal
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    //variable to check if type stormtrooper
    let typeTrooper = e.target.className.split(" ")[0];
    if(typeTrooper == "trooper"){
        let stormTrooperChecker = document.querySelector("." + e.target.className.split(" ")[1]);
        stormTrooperChecker.remove();
    }
    alert(e.x);
    console.log("Y: " + e.y);
});

//Character Movement
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if(e.key =='d'){
        vaderX += 2;
        darthVader.style.left = vaderX  + "px"; 
    }

    if(e.key =='a'){
        vaderX -= 2;
        darthVader.style.left = vaderX  + "px";
    }
});
```

```css
body{
    border: 0;
    background: black;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.deathStar {
    position: relative;
    display:flex;
    height: 700px;
    width: 700px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: darkgrey;
    top: 50%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.hole{
    display: flex;
    height: 100px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: gray;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-60PX);
}

.stormTrooper{
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}

.body{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
    width: 10px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.head{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    height: 7px;
    width: 9px;
    transform: translate(-5px, 1px);
    background-color: black;
}

.gun{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    height: 2px;
    width: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    transform: translate(-5px, 10px)
}

.legSplit{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    width: 1px;
    height: 8px;
    background-color: black;
    transform: translate(-5px, 22px);
}

.darthVader{
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    height: 30px;
    width: 10px;
    z-index: 3;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="deathStar" id="deathStar">
        <div class="darthVader"></div> 
    </div>
    <div class="hole"></div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the initial values of `vaderX` aren't the same as the X coordinate (or `style.left`) of the `darthVader` initial position.

`getBoundingClientRect` returns the position relative to the viewport. The `darthVader` element is inside an element with `position: relative`. The value `darthVader.style.left` is relative to the parent with a `position` that is not `static`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

> The Element.getBoundingClientRect() method returns a DOMRect object
> providing information about the size of an element and **its position
> relative to the viewport.** (...) Properties other than width and height
> are relative to the top-left of the viewport.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

> absolute (...)  It is positioned relative to its closest positioned
> ancestor, if any; otherwise, **it is placed relative to the initial
> containing block**. Its final position is determined by the values of
> top, right, bottom, and left.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block

> The size and position of an element are often impacted by its
> containing block. Most often, the containing block is the content area
> of an element's nearest block-level ancestor, but this is not always
> the case. (...) The process for identifying the containing block
> depends entirely on the value of the element's position property (...)

You fix the issue if you replace:

```js
let vaderX = window.scrollX + darthVader.getBoundingClientRect().left;
```

with:

```js
let vaderX = darthVader.offsetLeft;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft

> The HTMLElement.offsetLeft read-only property returns the number of
> pixels that the upper left corner of the current element is offset to
> the left **within the HTMLElement.offsetParent node**.